# How do I integrate Stripe into my Streamlit app?

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments, streamlit

I currently have a Streamlit app deployed on Heroku that essentially takes an Excel file, performs data analysis, and output the analysis as a downloadable link that the user presses to get the Excel file. It works great, however, I made this app for a small company, and I would like to privatize the app by making it only usable after a one-time payment has been made so the company can't make money off my app (they're very entrepreneurial and I know they're trying to rip me off). I found an example of someone who did a similar process with their Streamlit app https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/stripe-api-integration/13159. Although, I'm not sure what code I would need to implement this Stripe service, how I would need to adjust my current code, and if it's possible to do without AWS Services (because I have no knowledge of AWS). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd start with https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment at least. In any case you do need a backend of some kind, it doesn't have to be AWS.

Comment: @karllekko My app is run with Streamlit and the docs say to use Flask. I'm not sure how I would integrate the two. Also, I have no experience with backend development, so the simplest answer for that would be appreciated.

Comment: Well using Stripe requires a backend and some experience there. You don't have to use Flask either, you can use any web framework you're most familiar with(or none). The simplest option and requires no code is https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links ! But if you want to do something based on the payment succeeding(like set a database flag or something to allow access to your application like you're saying) that's inherently all backend stuff.

Comment: @karllekko Do you have any recommendations for the backend? i.e. Django